# How can i do List<User Defined Type> = List<User Defined Type2>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I Have Two Lists with User Defined Types 
e.g. `List<User_Master>` and `List<User_Master_Temp`> both the `User_Master` and `User_Master_Temp` contains the same type of variables with same name. 
how can i assign these type of lists  ? 
traditional way of doing is

```
userMaster.UserName = userMasterTemp.UserName;
userMaster.UserEmail = userMasterTemp.UserEmail;
userMaster.UserSalary = userMasterTemp.UserSalary;
```

Why I need this ?

I am using EF 5 (DataBase First Approach)and MVC 4, I apply my data annotation validation in model and if I Update my edmx file and then run custom tool, all my validations disappears.

So I wrote my own View Model Class which is same as that of Original Model Class and I apply my data annotation in that View Model Class.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to convert one custom instances to another using defined configuration or some convention. It has a convention to map properties if they have the same names and types are compatible, which work by default. Next code demonstrates the usage of it

```
void Main()
{
    List<UserMaster> users = new List<UserMaster>{
        new UserMaster{Name = "Bob",  Email = "bob@mail.ru",  Salary = 10},
        new UserMaster{Name = "Jack", Email = "jack@mail.ru", Salary = 20},
        new UserMaster{Name = "John", Email = "john@mail.ru", Salary = 40},
    };

    Mapper.CreateMap<UserMaster, UserMasterTemp>();

    List<UserMasterTemp> usersTemp = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserMaster>,
                                                List<UserMasterTemp>>(users);

    usersTemp.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

class UserMaster
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
class UserMasterTemp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    //formating for demo purposes
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}, Email: {1}, Salary: {2}", 
                              Name, Email, Salary);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Name: Bob,  Email: bob@mail.ru,  Salary: 10
Name: Jack, Email: jack@mail.ru, Salary: 20
Name: John, Email: john@mail.ru, Salary: 40
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User_Master.Select(m=>new User_Master_Temp(){/*assign the Properties*/});
```

and if you are using some object to object mapper you can use that i Use [Glue](http://glue.codeplex.com/) for doing this.

```
var Mapping = new Mapping<User_Master, User_Master_Temp>();
Mapping.AutoRelateEqualNames();
User_Master.Select(m=>Mapping.Map(m));
```

Comment: i have no idea about object to object mapper

Answer (score 1):

you can use the automapper to Map the objects.

here is the documentation :

[Click Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki)

you can get the AUTOMAPPER using the NUGET PACKAGE in the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to use tools, you can use this method:

```
public static void CopyIdenticalObjects(object source, object destination)
        {
            FieldInfo[] destinationFields = destination.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            foreach (FieldInfo sourceField in source.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
                for (int counter = 0; counter < destinationFields.Length; ++counter)
                    try
                    {
                        if (destinationFields[counter].Name.Equals(sourceField.Name))
                        {
                            destinationFields[counter].SetValue(destination, sourceField.GetValue(source));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
        }
```